# How to perform a function before a redirect with passport.authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, variables, post

I am using WebDevSimplifieds version of a login script. So far its working but I am stuck at the moment with a function I would like to to run before it redirects after logging in.

The user is on a login page where he puts in all credentials and if everything is correct, the user will be redirected to index.ejs(html). Before redirecting I would like to run a function which alters a server variable based on what the user put in into a specific field.

This is working, but of course there is no additional function.

```
app.post(
  '/login', 
  checkNotAuthenticated, 
    passport.authenticate('local', 
      {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true,
      }
    )
)
```

I would like to have something like that. The console.log command works, but the passport.authenticate not.

```
app.post(
  '/login', 
  checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    console.log("that works");
    passport.authenticate('local', 
      {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true,
      }
    )}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`passport.authenticate` returns a function that has the signature `(req, res, next)`, i.e. a middleware.

Compare [the source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/932c1b8a6ab17f81ff44a69825ce43c6434bb53a/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L94):

```
module.exports = function authenticate(passport, name, options, callback) {
  // ...

  return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    // ...
  };

  // ...
};
```

You need to call that function.

```
app.post(
  '/login', 
  checkNotAuthenticated,
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("that works");

    const authFunc = passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login',
      failureFlash: true,
    });

    authFunc(req, res, next);
  )}
)
```

Comment: I wasnt allowed to at the time I wrote my comment. Did that a few minutes later.

Comment: @Kai No worries. There is a certain percentage of new users who ask a question, and as soon as they have received a half-way working answer, they wander off and never return, leaving their threads open forever. Hence the relatively quick nudge.